# How to pass value to cgi script from HREF link

Tags: arrays, perl, html-table, cgi

I do have script with href that calls a cgi script, and I want to pass a value to cgi script from href..first script is link.cgi and it has a line like this:

```
 print "<TD align=center><FONT SIZE='4'><a href='../cgi-bin/call.cgi?param=$path1'>$v_rel</a></FONT>\n";
```

I do have these line in call.cgi:

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my ($param) = $cgi->param('param');
print ".....the value is $param\n";
```

I get error here when I click the link in which it calls call.cgi,I guess it does not pass the param to call.cgi, any good people out there can help on this..thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post error message?

Comment: I get this error when I click href:Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: any thought what could be the issue, I'm guessing the param is not passed to the cgi, but why as I'm sure the syntax is right in above case..

Comment: I don't think it's param issue, it looks fine. Can you please run the same .cgi on your linux terminal and post error/output?

Comment: @jkshah..no error when I run cgi, i get the print  is: .....the value is

Comment: Might be worth adding `use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;` at the beginning in order to display errors in browser. Also, atleast on my shared host, if I don't print a content type before printing i.e. `print $cgi->header;`, i'll receive a 500 error. Do you receive the error when hitting call.cgi directly in browser (no params)?

Comment: @Chris... I solved the problem, the problem was /usr/bin/perl -TW removing -TW did the job as it was tailor the value..thanks all for your time..

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. In future try to post your entire code, if need be simplify it but be sure it still replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `-T` is usually not a good solution. You probably have a potential security issue in your code, and perl with `-T` alarmed you about it. By removing `-T`, you just masked it but it's still there. The return value of `$cgi->param()` is tainted and has to be cleaned up before you pass it to many functions.

Instead, add `use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;` as proposed by @Chris, and if you still get this error have a look at your server error logs that will contain more information about the error.

Sometimes it helps being able to run from the command line and see the errors directly on the command line. Set `QUERY_STRING` to your parameter and run your script:

```
export REQUEST_METHOD=GET
export QUERY_STRING=param=WhateverYourPath1Is
perl /path/to/call.cgi
```

NB: you may have to define a few other CGI environment variables depending on your script.